# The url does not change at form submit?

Tags: python, django

I have some categories, like restaurants, sport and fitness, fast food etc.. I want to create dropdown menu with all categories and show different category items each time when different category is selected:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="{% url 'show-all-objects' category=category page_num=1 %}" method="POST" id="sort_form">
    <select data-placeholder="Categories:" class="utf_chosen_select_single" id="select_sort_category" name="select_sort_category" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option>Категориии</option>
        <option value="restaurants">Ресторанти</option>
        <option value="sportfitness">Спортни и фитнес</option>
        <option value="carservice">Автосервизи</option>
        <option value="beautysalon">Салони за красота</option>
        <option value="fastfood">Бързо хранене</option>
        <option value="carwash">Автомивки</option>
        <option value="fun">Забавлание</option>
        <option value="other">Други</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**Okay, this is the first link:**

```
http://localhost:8000/objects/all/restaurants/1/
```

Then from `<select>` select second option with value `sportfitness` It refresh page and show items from category `sportfitness` but url is still `http://localhost:8000/objects/all/restaurants/1/`
After that select third option with value `carservice` page is refresh again, this time url is changed to `http://localhost:8000/objects/all/sportfitness/1/` instead of `carservices` so it has delay 1 time.

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('user/<int:pk>/', views.UserObjectsView.as_view(), name='user-objects'),
    path('add/<str:category>/', views.add_object, name='add-object'),
    path('<str:category>/<int:pk>/<int:page_num>/', views.show_object, name='show-object'),
    #path('all/<str:category>/<int:page_num>/', views.show_all_objects, name="show-all-objects"),
    re_path(r'all/(?P<category>\w+)/(?P<page_num>\d+)/?/(?P<city>\d+)?', views.show_all_objects, name="show-all-objects"),
]
```

**views.py:**

```
def show_all_objects(request, category, page_num, city=None):
    params_map = {
        'restaurants': Restaurant,
        'sportfitness': SportFitness,
        'carservice': CarService,
        'beautysalon': BeautySalon,
        'fastfood': FastFood,
        'carwash': CarWash,
        'fun': Fun,
        'other': Other,
    }

    if request.method == 'POST':
        category = request.POST.get('select_sort_category')

    objects = Object.objects.instance_of(params_map.get(category)).order_by('rating')


    if city is not None:
        objects = objects.filter(city=city)

    paginator = Paginator(objects, 2)
    objects = paginator.get_page(page_num)

    context = {
        'objects': objects,
        'category': category,
        'page_num': page_num,
    }

    return render(request, 'show_all_objects.html', context)
```

I can provide more information as needed. Probably it's not Django problem, it is common programming problem, I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why it is happening?

`render` function does not change the URL.

---

#### How to solve it?

Instead of doing a post request on the `category that your view` is returning, do a post request on the `category that you select`.

e.g. if you current url is `http://localhost:8000/objects/all/restaurants/1/`, and you select `sportfitness`, then instead of doing a post request on `http://localhost:8000/objects/all/restaurants/1/` do a post request on `http://localhost:8000/objects/all/sportfitness/1/`.

This is how you can do it:

```
var url = "{% url 'show-all-objects' category=category page_num=1 %}";
var urlCategory = "{{ category }}";

$('#select_sort_category').on('change', function () {
    $('#sort_form').attr('action', url.replace(urlCategory, this.value)).submit();
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Somewhat.. I understand the problem, but how to change POST request ? url comes from here `{% url 'show-all-objects' category=category page_num=1 %}`

Comment: AJAX probably ? to get value from select ?

Comment: Avoid AJAX (though we can do it using AJAX as well). Just detect an on click event, modify the url, and submit. To get value do something like `var catagory = $("#select_sort_category").val();`

Comment: Ok, I did it, also edin your answer with code, which helps me, now answer is complete. I'm curious is there a way to do it without JS ? probably to change `render` to something else ?

Comment: If you don't want to change your code too much, then using `redirect` is an option. (But I doubt that it will add an extra request.)

Comment: I have updated the js code a little bit that you have added. (To avoid hardcoding the URL.)